# Flutter Firebase Another profile page shows my followers

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter Firebase. TI have listed my followers and follow, but when I go to another profile page, it shows my own followers, not the followers of the owner of the profile page. My codes are as follows. what should I do for this? I'm new to Flutter, can you help me? In other words, when I click the 'follow' button on that person's profile, I want the profiles that that user follows to be listed

Database

[image]

Follow_card

```
class FollowCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final snap;

  const FollowCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowCard> createState() => _FollowCardState();
}

class _FollowCardState extends State<FollowCard> {
  List<dynamic> followList = []; // shouldn't use dynamic

  getdata() async {
    List<dynamic> followers = [];

    final currentUserSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .get();

    // get followerIds
    List<String> followIds =
        List.from(currentUserSnapshot.data()!['following']);
    // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
    for (int i = 0; i < followIds.length; i++) {
      var followId = followIds[i];
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(followId)
          .get();

      // push that data into the temp list variable as we are going
      // to use that in to setState
      followers.add(data);
    }
    setState(() => followList = followers);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use the listView builder to render the list of followers card
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: followList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var followerItem = followList[index];
            print('photoUrl');

            return _buildFollowersCard(followerItem['photoUrl'],
                followerItem['username'], followerItem['uid']);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFollowersCard(String photoUrl, String username, String uid) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: mobileBackgroundColor,
      child: Card(
        child: Column(children: [
          //Header
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 4,
              horizontal: 16,
            ).copyWith(right: 0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 16,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    photoUrl,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ProfileScreen(uid: uid)));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            username,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Follow_screen

```
class FollowScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FollowScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowScreen> createState() => _FollowScreenState();
}

class _FollowScreenState extends State<FollowScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'Resim/logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FollowCard(
              snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

profil_screen (button)

```
child: buildStatColumn(followers, 'Takipçi'),
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    FollowScreen()));
                                      },
```

Comment: Dont do this >>> stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),

declare a variable and initialize it inside initstate and just put this on stream >> stream : yourVariable

Comment: Can you answer by changing the codes above? People can be informed by seeing the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow_card

```
class FollowCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final snap;
  final String uid;

  const FollowCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.snap,
    required this.uid,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowCard> createState() => _FollowCardState();
}

class _FollowCardState extends State<FollowCard> {
  List<dynamic> followList = []; // shouldn't use dynamic

  getdata() async {
    List<dynamic> followers = [];

    final currentUserSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(widget.uid)
        .get();

    // get followerIds
    List<String> followIds =
        List.from(currentUserSnapshot.data()!['following']);
    // loop through all ids and get associated user object by userID/followerID
    for (int i = 0; i < followIds.length; i++) {
      var followId = followIds[i];
      var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(followId)
          .get();

      // push that data into the temp list variable as we are going
      // to use that in to setState
      followers.add(data);
    }
    setState(() => followList = followers);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // use the listView builder to render the list of followers card
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: followList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var followerItem = followList[index];
            print('photoUrl');

            return _buildFollowersCard(followerItem['photoUrl'],
                followerItem['username'], followerItem['uid']);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFollowersCard(String photoUrl, String username, String uid) {
    return Container(
      height: 70,
      width: double.infinity,
      color: mobileBackgroundColor,
      child: Card(
        child: Column(children: [
          //Header
          Container(
            height: 40,
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 4,
              horizontal: 16,
            ).copyWith(right: 0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 16,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    photoUrl,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) =>
                                        ProfileScreen(uid: uid)));
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            username,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

follow_screen

```
class FollowScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uid;
  const FollowScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.uid,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FollowScreen> createState() => _FollowScreenState();
}

class _FollowScreenState extends State<FollowScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Image.asset(
          'Resim/logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => FollowCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(), uid: widget.uid),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Profile_screen button

```
TextButton( onPressed: () async {DocumentSnapshot result =
                                            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                                .collection('users')
                                                .doc(FirebaseAuth
                                                    .instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                                .get();
                                        Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    FollowScreen(
                                                      uid: userData['uid'],
                                                    )));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you always get the data for the currently logged in user, because you pass `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid` to the call to Firestore. Instead you should pass the actual uid of the user whose profile page you are currently visiting.
You could do something like:

```
class FollowCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userId;
```

...

```
getdata() async {
    List<dynamic> followers = [];
    final currentUserSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(widget.userId)
    .get();
```

...

Comment: Undefined name 'userId'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. I get an error.

Comment: You have to pass it to your class that's why I added 'final String userId' as a field to your class (right at the top of my answer).

Comment: I did the same. Then I added the property userId: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid to the follow_screen, but the followcard userid gave this error

Comment: Or you can try to extract it from your snap, but you need to define it in your class in any case.

Comment: Can you contact me by mail? To show you the error. tolunaykurtt@gmail.com

Comment: Again, the point is not to use FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid but the actual uid of the user whose profile page you are currently visiting.

Comment: Here's how I can get access to that uid?

Comment: You are passing a snap property to your class (and not doing anything with it as far as I can see...). You should try to see what is in there and if you can extract the uid from there. Maybe you can do : getdata() async {
    List<dynamic> followers = [];
  final String userId = snap['uid'];
    final currentUserSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userId)
        .get();

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: As Tolunay Kurt found out, it needed to be .doc(widget.userId) instead of .doc(userId)